# Linear transformation that close to be injective.

Tags: linear-transformations

In my research, I am looking for a linear transformation $T:\mathbb{F}_2^n \rightarrow \mathbb{F}_2^m$ that shrinks vectors to vectors with lower dimension, i.e., $m << n$ and has the property that vectors with low weight (i.e., vectors with a small number of non-zero entries), specifically for any subset $B$ of basis vectors of size $k$, the transformation restricted to $B$, denoted as $\left.T\right|{\text{Span}(B)}$, will be injective. I have found that there are no such transformations with the parameters that I need. However, it is not necessary for the transformation to be fully injective; it is sufficient for the transformation to be "close" to being injective. Formally,

$\textbf{Definition: d to 1 function:}$ A function $f$ is a $(d-1)$ function if for any $y\in \text{Im}(f)$, there exist at most $d$ distinct $x_1, \ldots, x_d$ such that $\forall i, f(x_i)=y$.

A very basic fact about linear transformations is that a linear transformation is injective if and only if $\text{dim}(\text{Ker}(T)) = 0$. This led me to think that there might be a relation between the dimension reduction of the kernel and the minimal $d$ for which the transformation is a $d$ to 1 function.

Are there any research papers or studies related to this topic?

Comment: In linear algebra, for any linear transformation $f: V_1 \longrightarrow V_2$ between two vector spaces, you have $\mathrm{dim}(\mathrm{Im}(f)) + \mathrm{dim}(\mathrm{Ker}(f)) = \mathrm{dim}(V_1)$. Applied in your case, since $\mathrm{Im}(f) \subset V_2$, you have $\mathrm{dim}(\mathrm{Ker}(f))\geq m-n$ and thus $d\geq 2^{m-n}$.

Comment: @EricBrier Can I claim that there exists a Linear function that $d = 2^{m-n}$, and if I need that only for subspaces with lower dimension can I get any improvement?

Comment: I'm afraid no improvement is possible because of the inequality. You can however ensure that it is an equality by making sure the image of $T$ is the whole $\mathbb{F}_2^m$.